# Why Unison doesn't work in described situation?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, devops, unison

In my project i have structure like this one:
[image]

I am using unison repeat=watch to sync folders A and B. It's working well when i put something to dir A or B, but when i place a file in folder C it doesnt work. File is visible in B, but not in A. C is mounted as B in docker. C is also AWS EFS share. Im accessing efs through ec2 instance. Docker is running on Fargate.

Can anybody tells me why it doesn't work in this config?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Do you get an error message? Does it seem like it succeeds but the file you put in C isn't transferred? Is this file visible in B?

Comment: it is not perform sync from B -> A. File is visible in B. And there is no errors

Comment: My guess would be the protocol implementation used for the AWS share doesn't support watching for directory changes. I'm not too familiar with AWS so it's only a guess. You could check that manually with the inotify-tools (use inotifywait on B, in another terminal create a file in C, see if you got an event). If that's the case, I guess the only thing you can do is sync every X minutes instead.

Comment: Ok. I'll try that. Thanks.